# Building a Web Application

Tags: php

I have been using wordpress for year, reverse engineering it for whatever purpose it may be.

I've had enough. I'd like to build this next project using tables that I predetermine and choose and hook up my website to them. I know what I'm doing with PHP but not SQL; I am also comfortable building tables in PHPmyADMIN. I am fluent in CSS, HTML, JS etc...

SO what I am looking for is a set of tools to help me in this task that provide basic functions for reading and writing to a database log in etc.. but nothing as convoluted and targeted as wordpress.

What am I looking for?

Comment: So you are basically looking for a PHP web framework?

Comment: Possibly. Something simple thought that is easy to bespoke and secure

Comment: Does it need it be PHP? Otherwise I would recommend Django written in Python or Ruby on Rails written in Ruby which are both pretty common in web development.

Comment: Never used Ruby and don't have time to learn another language.

Comment: -1. do not use tag 'tools' see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tools/info

Answer (score 2):

Purely subjective answer, but [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) and [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) are pretty well known and support starting points.

If you're familiar with CMS's, then Joomla has the [**platform only**](http://api.joomla.org/li_Joomla-Platform.html).  We've got a guy working with that, and constantly refers to the the Joomla CMS for examples and ideas on implementation, but aside from the framework it's pure custom code.

Comment: Mine recommending Yii :)

Comment: How hard would it be to code it outright.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but if you mean coding from the ground up, you don't need a framework - that's the purpose of a framework, to have all the tried and true groundwork in place so that you can focus on coding your application with consistent "standard" functions.  Which is "best" depends on what your needs are, or whatever criteria you would measure it by.  Personally, I look at how well the community supports it so that I know I can find answers when I get stuck.